# How can I pass parameters to my program when debugging?

Tags: delphi, debugging

I am using Delphi 5. If I have to run my project I have to run it from the command prompt and pass the parameters with cmd. I want to debug the project step by step. How do I pass paramaters through the IDE or any other way so that I can debug the program?

Answer (score 18):

The menu option is under `Run -> Parameters`. Just fill in the "Parameters" box, leave "Host application" blank.

[image: Run parameters]

Comment: +1 Blimey, you've got to quick around here to get an answer in!